# does $elemMatch in $projection stage make use of indexes?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

If there are indexes for that field, will the $elemMatch operator use it during $projection?

Comment: I agree with [@Joe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74905673/20042973). But I'm a little curious about the specifics of your question. In what way(s) were you thinking that the index may be used there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a $project stage will not make use of an index.

Indexes are used for locating documents that match a query without needing to read the entire collection.

A $project stage is used to mutate documents already in the pipeline, so it will never retrieve documents from the collection.

If the pipeline starts with a $project stage, the query executor will add an implicit collection scan (effectively a `{$match: {}}`) before the projection.