# Is there a way to filter array of subdocuments in the $match stage?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      field_nest: { $elemMatch: { /* conditions */ } }
    }
  }
])
```

This is my current set up. In addition to matching the parent document, it needs to also return only the subdocument that matches the `$elemMatch`.

Otherwise, I would have to `$unwind` and `$match` again. But this would no long be able to use the index. The idea is to be able to use the indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the `$match` stage selects documents to pass along the pipeline, it does not modify the documents being passed along.

You can use `$elemMatch` in the `$match` stage to select the documents, and then use `$filter` in an `$addFields` stage to filter out the non-matching elements.

Perhaps something like:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$match: {
       field_nest: { $elemMatch: { /* conditions */ } }
    }},
    {$addFields: {
       field_nest: {$filter:{
          input: "$field_nest",
          as: "item",
          cond: { /* conditions */ }
       }}
    }}
])
```

This may be able to use an index, depending on the exact conditions and available indexes.

For example, if the query were

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {$match: {
    field_nest:{$elemMatch:{a:1,b:2}}
  }}
])
```

It could use an  index on `{"field_nest.a":1,"field_nest.b":1}`, but it could not use an index on `{field_nest:1}` or `{"field_next.c":1, "field_next.a":1}`.

If the query were

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {$match: {
    top_field: "name",
    some_value: {$gte: "never"},
    field_nest:{$elemMatch:{a:1,b:2}}
  }}
])
```

the query executor would look at all of the available indexes, but may use an index that does not include the array field.

If the query were

```
  {$match: {
    top_field: "name",
    some_value: {$gte: "never"},
    field_nest:{$elemMatch:{a:{$regex:"unanchored"},b:2}}
  }}
])
```

it would not be able to use an index for selecting `field_nest.a`, but might be able to use one for `field_nest.b`.

The determination of whether or not an index will be used depends greatly on the exact nature of the match conditions and available indexes.

Comment: I am sure what you mean by `may be able to use an index`. Are you saying that you are guessing? Or will it actually work assuming the existence of indexes? Can you point to documentation that discusses indexes with `$addFields`?

Comment: I'll edit the answer to expand on that.

Comment: @BigCatPublicSafetyLaw query planner is not always that straightforward, and generally speaking you cannot guarantee a particular index will be used unless you explicitly hint it.  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-plans/  Now aggregation. Index can be used only on the first stage, with few exceptions, and it will never be used on projection stage. To make it clear, removing subdocuments from the result is a projection in one form or another. The best you can get is to use index to find **documents** that have at least 1 matching subdocument, then you re-shape them as needed.

Comment: regarding the second example. if query operator uses `an index that does not include the array field.`, then it would not have any effect?

Comment: It would only use an index that doesn't include an  array field if another index exists that supports the other parts of the match expression.

Comment: Didn't we already have the index/$project discussion in [this question from OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74903923/does-elemmatch-in-projection-stage-make-use-of-indexes) just a few days ago?

Comment: This discussion was about index use in the $match as the first stage of a pipeline, which can actually use an index, and  Index usage is a complicated topic in MongoDB.

Comment: If there are multiple matches during the `$addFields` stage, how to specify to only select the first one?

Comment: `$arrayElemAt` is one option